# Laravel Telescope - 403 Forbidden

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have implemented Laravel Telescope and I can only acces if `APP_ENV=local`

I have followed Laravel's documentation and I changed code in `TelescopeServiceProvider.php` (take in care that my evironments are called loca, dev, testing and prod).

The only way I can access `Telescope` is changing `APP_ENV=local` in each enviroment.

Does anyone knows which can be by issue?

Regards

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Telescope\IncomingEntry;
use Laravel\Telescope\Telescope;
use Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeApplicationServiceProvider;

class TelescopeServiceProvider extends TelescopeApplicationServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // Telescope::night();

        $this->hideSensitiveRequestDetails();

        Telescope::filter(function (IncomingEntry $entry) {
            if ($this->app->environment('local') || $this->app->environment('dev') || $this->app->environment('test') || $this->app->environment('prod')) {
                return true;
            }


            return $entry->isReportableException() ||
                   $entry->isFailedRequest() ||
                   $entry->isFailedJob() ||
                   $entry->isScheduledTask() ||
                   $entry->hasMonitoredTag();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Prevent sensitive request details from being logged by Telescope.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function hideSensitiveRequestDetails()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment('local') || $this->app->environment('dev') || $this->app->environment('test') || $this->app->environment('prod')) {
            return;
        }

        Telescope::hideRequestParameters(['_token']);

        Telescope::hideRequestHeaders([
            'cookie',
            'x-csrf-token',
            'x-xsrf-token',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Register the Telescope gate.
     *
     * This gate determines who can access Telescope in non-local environments.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function gate()
    {
        Gate::define('viewTelescope', function ($user) {
            return in_array($user->email, [
                //
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

This is my `confif/app.php` file

```
/*
 * Application Service Providers...
 */
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
//App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: without diving in deep I've just one question for first: do you've runned "php artisan config:cache"  after each .env changes ??

Comment: @boolfalse thanks for your reply. Yes, I executed ```php artisan config:cache``` and still problem issue exists

Comment: Did you remove the TelescopeServiceProvider service provider registration from your app configuration file?

Comment: @SevanNerse thanks for the reply. Yes, I removed it, I have updated my question and pasted that code. Regards

Comment: Please, also share your AppServiceProvider where you register TelescopeServiceProvider.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**By default, you will only be able to access this dashboard in the `local` environment**.

Within your `app/Providers/TelescopeServiceProvider.php` file, there is a `gate` method. This authorization gate controls access to Telescope in **non-local environments**. You are free to modify this gate as needed to restrict access to your Telescope installation:

```php
/**
 * Register the Telescope gate.
 *
 * This gate determines who can access Telescope in non-local environments.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewTelescope', function ($user) {
        return in_array($user->email, [
            // Your users
            'user@yourapp.tld',
        ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue. It wasnt clear for me while reading Telescope documentation. Thanks @Wahyu Kristianto

Answer (score 7):

You may override `authorization()` method in `Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeApplicationServiceProvider` in your `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider` and include your enviroment name.

**But be careful with it.**

```
/**
 * Configure the Telescope authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function authorization()
{
    $this->gate();

    Telescope::auth(function ($request) {
        return app()->environment('local') ||
               Gate::check('viewTelescope', [$request->user()]);
    });
}
```

to

```
...
return app()->environment(['local', 'testing']) ||
       Gate::check('viewTelescope', [$request->user()]);
...
```

Comment: This have hepl! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use laravel as api application, you can use auth by cookie. Just add cookie secretTelescope and run it.

```
Gate::define('viewTelescope', function (?User $user) {
    return array_key_exists('secretTelescope', $_COOKIE);
);
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I have solve this by changing this method and .env value

this is located in this path App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider.php

```
/**
     * Register the Telescope gate.
     *
     * This gate determines who can access Telescope in non-local environments.
     */
    protected function gate(): void
    {
        Gate::define('viewTelescope', function ($user) {
            return $user->username == 'super_admin';
        });
    }
```

this will work and if you see it is not working then you should check your .env file

add this line if not exists

```
TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true
```

then check **APP_ENV** if it is local then ok but if not then change it to local

I hope you problem will be solved

Comment: This only works because you're using APP_ENV=local, so it is not calling the gate() function. Also using APP_ENV=local in production might leave your system vulnerable.